# Powershell Script Filename Increment

Tags: powershell

Within Powershell I want to automate the process of changing the file name of a group of files and copy the latest version of a similar file to that directory.

1. Delete oldest

   ```
   (file3.bak) --> none
   ```
2. Increase filename of current files in backup directory

   ```
       (file1.bak) --> (file2.bak)
       (file2.bak) --> (file3.bak)
   ```
3. Copy latest version of file from another directory to this backup directory

   ```
   (newestfile.txt)   --> (file1.bak)
   ```

This is as far as I have gotten and am stuck:

```
$path = "c:\temp"
cd $path

$count = (get-childitem $path -name).count
Write-Host "Number of Files: $count"

$items = Get-ChildItem | Sort Extension -desc | Rename-Item -NewName {"gapr.ear.rollback$count"}

$items | Sort Extension -desc | ForEach-Object  -begin { $count= (get-childitem $path -name).count }  -process { rename-item $_ -NewName "gappr.ear.rollback$count"; $count-- }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to all who responded. Your help was appreciated

```
#Directory to complete script in
$path = "c:\temp"
cd $path

#Writes out number of files in directory to console
$count = (get-childitem $path -name).count
Write-Host "Number of Files: $count"

#Sorts items by decsending order
$items = Get-ChildItem | Sort Extension -desc 

#Deletes oldest file by file extension number
del $items[0]

#Copy file from original directory to backup directory
Copy-Item c:\temp2\* c:\temp

#Sorts items by decsending order
$items = Get-ChildItem | Sort Extension -desc

#Renames files in quotes after NewName argument
$items | ForEach-Object  -begin { $count= (get-childitem $path -name).count }  -process { rename-item $_ -NewName "file.bak$count"; $count-- }
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this? Remove '-Whatif's to do the real thing.

```
$files = @(gci *.bak | sort @{e={$_.LastWriteTime}; asc=$true})

if ($files)
{
    del $files[0] -Whatif
    for ($i = 1; $i -lt $files.Count; ++$i)
     { ren $files[$i] $files[$i - 1] -Whatif }
}
```

Comment: The sort is unnecessary complex though; `Sort-Object LastWriteTime` does the same thing (I tend to always write the whole command in scripts for better readibility).