# cmd script: delete old, increment, copy

Tags: batch-file, cmd

This is [the same question I had before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10287762/powershell-script-filename-increment) but now it has to be in a bat file.

1) I want to delete "file.rollback3"

2) Then I want to increment all the files up by 1 
file.rollback1 --> file.rollback 2
file.rollback2 --> file.rollback 3

3) copy file.data from different directory to the rollback directory

This is what I have so far...

```
    @echo off
set path=c:\temp3
cd %path%
set fileCount=0
for /f "tokens=1*" %%a in ('dir /a * /b /s') do (
       call set /a fileCount=%%fileCount%%+1)
echo %fileCount%
set /a delFile=(%fileCount%-1)
echo %delFile%
del *.rollback%delFile%
pause
set counter=%delFile%
:incrementLoop
IF "%counter%" geq "0"
(
    ren \.rollback%counter% \.rollback
    set /a %counter% = %counter%-1
    goto incrementLoop
)
goto incrementLoop
pause
```

Comment: Nice! But do you have any questions? Or do you only want to say that something doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SET "rollbackdir=..."
SET "differentdir=..."
SET "filename=..."
SET "numcopies=3"
FOR /L %%i IN (%numcopies%,-1,1) DO (
  IF %%i == %numcopies% (
    DEL "%rollbackdir%\%filename%.rollback%%i" 2>NUL
  ) ELSE (
    SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
    RENAME "%rollbackdir%\%filename%.rollback%%i" "%filename%.rollback!next!" 2>NUL
    ENDLOCAL
  )
  SET next=%%i
)
COPY "%differentdir%\%filename%.data" "%rollbackdir%"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
cd C:\temp3
for %%f in (*.rollback?) do set delFile=%%f
echo del %delFile%
pause
set lastFile=%delFile:~-1%
set /A lastButOne=lastFile-1
for /L %%i in (%lastButOne%,-1,1) do (
   echo ren *.rollback%%i *.rollback!lastFile!
   set lastFile=%%i
)
echo copy C:\different\directory\file.data file.rollback1
pause
```

Comment: The OP said they want to delete the rollback #3 but this script will delete the last rollback found. What if it is not #3 (yet)?

Comment: OP's code shown above do a search for the last rollback file and delete it, so I assumed he wants to do that. Otherwise a simple `del rollback3` `ren rollback2 rollback3` `ren rollback1 rollback2` program would solve the problem, right?

Comment: You are right, I was just satisfied with their verbal description and didn't have much of a look at their script. And yes, the three commands you gave an example of (plus `copy`) would indeed be enough, but, well, we are not looking for an easy way, are we? Nor is the OP, it seems. :)